# Subjonctif présent dans une conditionnelle Inversion sujet-verbe

Tags: conjugaison, conditionnel, concordance-des-temps

Bonjour

J'aimerais confirmer la correction grammaticale (concordance des temps) plus l'orthographe dans ce cas d'inversion sujet-verbe.

> N'eussé-je été contraint de partir, j'aurais eu l'occasion de voir les montagnes.

C'est une autre façon d'exprimer :

> Si je n'avais pas été contraint de partir, etc.

Le subjonctif passé est-il approprié ici, et l'orthographe est-elle bien avec é pour l'inversion sujet-verbe ?

Answer (score 1):

Autant utiliser le conditionnel passé deuxième forme partout :

> N'eussé-je été contraint de partir, j'eusse eu l'occasion de voir les montagnes.

L'accent est au choix aigu (traditionnel) ou grave (plus conforme à la prononciation), suivant que l'on respecte l'orthographe classique ou les rectifications de 1990.